# Exception handling for reading from a cached data

Tags: java

My question about handling an exception that is related to getting data from a list, that the list if filled with an API.
To be more specific, I have a method that is getting all the data from an API, and in ANOTHER method I want to search or filter that data. But I want it to throw an exception when the data is not found. how can I do this?

Here is my code

```
  public CommitResponse getOneCommitInfo(String commitHash) {
    CommitResponse commit = new CommitResponse();
    for (int i = 0; i < allCommitsList.size(); i++) {
      if (((CommitResponse) allCommitsList.get(i)).getHash().equals(commitHash)) {
        commit = (CommitResponse) allCommitsList.get(i);
      }
    }
    return commit;
  }
```

This code always returns 200 status code, as it is not a real endpoint that is talking with API, and it is only talking with the cached data.
I want to add 404 status code for it and I need it to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Throw `HttpStatusCodeException`

`throw new HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`

Comment: How should be the condition that throws an exception? some thing like `if commit.name()==null`?? Is there other condition fo it? Do I need a break in my loops?

Answer (score 0):

Try catching an Exception with the final variable "commit" you referenced on the return statement or use the if statements to return None or string if failed to return any data from the API you're using.

Comment: could you please send a code structure? I don't know where should I put to avoid traversing unnecessary items